# Python Tkinter Menu creation not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, menu, python-3.5

I am new to programming and am trying to create a menu in Python with the Tkinter package. But whenever I run the script in IDLE, all that is displayed is the top level (root) window.

Here is my script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root.option_add('*tearOff', False)

menubar1 = Menu(root)
root.configure(menu = menubar1)
file = Menu(menubar1)
edit = Menu(menubar1)
help_ =  Menu(menubar1)
tools = Menu(menubar1)
other = Menu(menubar1)

menubar1.add_cascade(menu = file, label = 'File')
menubar1.add_cascade(menu = edit, label = 'Edit')
menubar1.add_cascade(menu = help_, label = 'Help')
menubar1.add_cascade(menu = tools, label = 'Tools')
menubar1.add_cascade(menu = other, label = 'Other')
```

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't even run, as it's missing the `tkinter.Tk` instance (probably saved in `root`) and the `root.mainloop`. If I add those parts, it shows up fine for me.

Comment: the answer is so small it should even get a defined answer just a comment

Comment: did you try run it without IDLE ? IDLE was created with `tkinter` so sometimes can be conflict. But IDLE is only tool to develop code and when code is ready then you don't use IDLE to run it.

Comment: TidB, what do you mean the tkinter.Tk instance?

Comment: See my answer (basically, Tk() defines your root: `root = tkinter.Tk()`)

Answer (score 1):

As comments have pointed out, it's surprising that your code worked at all: root is not defined before you try to use `option_add` on it, so it will trigger  `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`.

But it *will* work if you define it. Someone's already commented with the solution. The `tkinter.Tk` instance is how you define your root to create a window in the first place. `mainloop()` is what you do to maintain that window. It's even easier than it sounds:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk # you could just say 'import tkinter', but 'tk' is easier to type

root = tk.Tk() # or, as @TidB mentioned, tkinter.Tk() if you're importing it as it is

root.option_add('*tearOff', False)
# insert all your code....
# and so on...
menubar1.add_cascade(menu = other, label = 'Other')

root.mainloop() # keeps the window up
```

Basically, just add mainloop() and Tk().

Also, since `from tkinter import *` naturally imports everything, you almost certainly do not need `from tkinter import ttk` (your second line of code).